# Which event is getting fired after moving out of the jquery-autocomplete widget?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jquery-ui 1.9 for jquery-autocomplete widget. 
I am tryingto change the background color with blue and font color with white of the list item while hovering the jquery autocomplete menu item list. 
I am able to change background color while hovering list item by adding css class,and also able to change font color while hovering list item by adding focus function .

```
_focus: function (event, ui) {
   event.preventDefault();     
    var htmlString= $('.ui-autocomplete').html();
    //Recently unFocused Element
    var foundUnFocusedEle = $(htmlString).find('.focusedElement');
    if(foundUnFocusedEle.length != 0) {
    var unFocusedEleId = $(foundUnFocusedEle).attr('id');
    var unFocusedEleHtml = $('#'+unFocusedEleId).html();
    if($(unFocusedEleHtml).hasClass('add-search-result-label') 
    && $(unFocusedEleHtml).hasClass('add-search-result-sublabel')) {
    $('#'+(foundUnFocusedEle).attr('id')).find('.add-search-result-label').removeClass('hover-search-result-label');
    $('#'+(foundUnFocusedEle).attr('id')).find('.add-search-result-label').addClass('search-result-label');
    $('#'+(foundUnFocusedEle).attr('id')).find('.add-search-result-label').removeClass('add-search-result-label');

    $('#'+(foundUnFocusedEle).attr('id')).find('.add-search-result-sublabel').removeClass('hover-search-result-sublabel');
    $('#'+(foundUnFocusedEle).attr('id')).find('.add-search-result-sublabel').addClass('search-result-sublabel');
    $('#'+(foundUnFocusedEle).attr('id')).find('.add-search-result-sublabel').removeClass('add-search-result-sublabel');
    }
    $('#'+unFocusedEleId).removeClass('focusedElement');
    }
    //ui-state-focus
var foundUiStateFocus = $(htmlString).find('.ui-state-focus');
            //console.log(foundUiStateFocus);
            if(foundUiStateFocus.hasClass('ui-state-focus')) {
                //console.log('it has ui-state-focus');
                var focusedEleId = $(foundUiStateFocus).attr('id');
                //console.log('id: '+focusedEleId);
                $('#'+focusedEleId).addClass('focusedElement');
                var focusedEleHtml = $('#'+focusedEleId).html();
                if($(focusedEleHtml).hasClass('search-result-label') && $(focusedEleHtml).hasClass('search-result-sublabel')) {
                    //console.log('it has search-result-label');
                    //console.log($('#'+(foundUiStateFocus).attr('id')).find('.search-result-label'));
                    $('#'+(foundUiStateFocus).attr('id')).find('.search-result-label').addClass('add-search-result-label');
                    $('#'+(foundUiStateFocus).attr('id')).find('.search-result-label').removeClass('search-result-label');

                    $('#'+(foundUiStateFocus).attr('id')).find('.search-result-sublabel').addClass('add-search-result-sublabel');
                    $('#'+(foundUiStateFocus).attr('id')).find('.search-result-sublabel').removeClass('search-result-sublabel');

                    $('#'+(foundUiStateFocus).attr('id')).find('.add-search-result-label').addClass('hover-search-result-label');
                    $('#'+(foundUiStateFocus).attr('id')).find('.add-search-result-sublabel').addClass('hover-search-result-sublabel');
                }
            }
        }
```

Now when I hovering a list item, font color and background color chnaged but when i come out from the widget or move to search text box. 
I need to change font color with orginal color instead of white.
So I have create mouseout / mouseleave function, but it's not getting called. 
Can anybody tell me which event / function is getting called when you hover over the list and then come out from the widget.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a delegated handler as shown below worked for me.

```
$(document).on('mouseout', '.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu', function() {
 console.log('trigget');
});
```